# Cannot place order

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, paypal

I have a new magento store and while doing order checkout testing, all steps are ok till confirming the order, a pop up error is appearing with error

> Cannot place order".

I have setup successfully paypal as payment gateway, error is appearing while checking out using paypal checkout and with credit card payment.

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Please check var/log/exception.log and post the error you find in this file so we can help you debug the issue

Comment: hi. i am also facing this issue on my website https://www.depoto.com/ .. when i checkout with registered user details., that is loading only on place order button. but fine with guest user.